# Upload multiple images on webserver

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

In my iOS app I want to upload around 400 images on web server. What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AFNetworking with batch upload in the background.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking